# I have an error with npm install, can someone explain it?

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, npm, npm-install

When I try `npm install react-color`, it shows me this error:

> ```
> npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
> npm ERR! Invalid package name "@types/" of package "@types/@react-navigation/native": name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
> ```

The same happened with `npm install react-dom` or others `npm install`. Can someone exlain why is it so?

Here are my dependencies :

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~11.2.3",
    "expo-cli": "^5.4.3",
    "expo-constants": "^13.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "^3.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-video": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-native-web-webview": "^1.0.2",
    "react-color": "2.19.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.18",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```

Comment: are you using typescript on your project?

Comment: Typo: `"@types/": "react-navigation/native",` should be `"@types/react-navigation/native": SOME_VERSION_NUMBER,`

Comment: I corrected this, there's still an error

Comment: I am indeed using typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the @ infront of react-navigation part in url.
Check npm website for more info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-navigation

The error basically says that the package name you added is incorrect because the path has characters not allowed in URLs.

Comment: But I don't use an url?

Comment: The path to package is a url, you added the react-native part in the version side, you should add it like this: "@types/react-native": "0.67.7"

Comment: If I use this : "@types/react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10", i got : `Invalid package name "@types/react-navigation/native" of package "@types/react-navigation/native@^6.0.10": name can only contain URL-friendly characters`